# Are there any invalid characters for an ext3 filename?

Tags: linux, ext3

Which characters are invalid for an ext3 filename?  I imagine that at least `/` is an invalid character and probably `\0`.  Is there an official list somewhere?

I'm not exactly sure where to look for this information, so please tell me where you found it.

Comment: An interesting, albeit lengthy, read: [Fixing Unix/Linux/POSIX Filenames](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just those two.

From the [wikipedia page on ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3):

> Allowed characters in filenames - All bytes except NULL and '/'

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the stats at the side of the wikipedia page.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

/ seems to be allowed, at least on ext3 (supposedly in all, ext, ext2 & ext3 at least, likely also ext4) - just try this:

```
f='test/file'; echo "Test: '${f}'"
for c in touch ll rm ;do
eval "${c} '${f}'"
done
```

That will create "test/file", surprised me too... It will create it, show it with ls command and finally remove it with rm

You can type it on one line in bash:

```
$ f='test/file';for c in touch ll rm ;do eval "${c} '${f}'";done
```

So / seems to be (bizerrely) allowed in filenames - probably many tools can get confused with such though...

Comment: Cool trick, though probably ill-advised on production systems :-)

Comment: Errr… do you have a directory called 'test'? That'll make a difference: `touch: cannot touch 'test/file': No such file or directory`

Comment: Though useful as a joke to pull on one's assistants.

Comment: No just managed to create a file named "test/file" - would be interesting to try it with existing directory named test... It might not even give trouble, after all, the / at the end of directory name isn't really part of it's name... So I could imagine them actually working together... It'll look confusing though... Or did you mean you actually tried it? :)